# Merging Multiple google sheet data into 1 google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, merge

Hi Im trying to merge multiple google sheets into a single google sheet. Importrange() and Query() will not work as there would be no constant number of google sheet file. I want to have a table of google sheet url reference and a formula that will capture these urls and merge into one

so far i haven't achieved anything

Comment: If you have a list of URLs you can use REDUCE to process them and stack them. For example: `=REDUCE(,TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(a,v,VSTACK(a,IMPORTRANGE(v,.....)))` Try and post a more concrete example and what you've been trying